# Reverse Grayscale Image Pixel by Pixel

Tags: c, image, filtering

I'm trying to write a C program that takes a `.raw` grayscale image and reverses it, pixel by pixel.

I store each pixel in a 1D `char` array, and then write each pixel to an output file, just in opposite order.

My program works if I try to reproduce the image, but if I try modifying the indices of my array, I produce an unreadable file.

**Reproduce Original**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    char ipath[64], opath[64], *rev, px;
    int i, row, read, width, height;

    printf("Name of input file: ");
    scanf("%s", ipath);
    printf("Name of output file: ");
    scanf("%s", opath);

    printf("Width of image: ");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    printf("Height of image: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);

    fin = fopen(ipath, "rb");
    fout = fopen(opath, "wb");

    rev = (char *)malloc(width * sizeof(char));

    row = 0;
    while(row < height)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            read = fread(&px, sizeof(char), 1, fin);
            rev[i] = px;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
            if(i < width && row < height)
                fwrite(&rev[i], sizeof(char), 1, fout);

        row++;
    }

    fclose(fout);
    fclose(fin);

    return 0;
}
```

**Reverse Image**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    char ipath[64], opath[64], *rev, px;
    int i, row, read, width, height;

    printf("Name of input file: ");
    scanf("%s", ipath);
    printf("Name of output file: ");
    scanf("%s", opath);

    printf("Width of image: ");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    printf("Height of image: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);

    fin = fopen(ipath, "rb");
    fout = fopen(opath, "wb");

    rev = (char *)malloc(width * sizeof(char));

    row = 0;
    while(row < height)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            read = fread(&px, sizeof(char), 1, fin);
            rev[width - 1 - i] = px;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
            if(i < width && row < height)
                fwrite(&rev[i], sizeof(char), 1, fout);

        row++;
    }

    fclose(fout);
    fclose(fin);

    return 0;
}
```

For testing purposes, I've just used `scanf()` though I'm aware of its issues.

Comment: As far as I understand, the restoring algorithm should be exactly the same as the reversing one. But it's not the case here.

Comment: The restoring one writes pixels from rev starting at `0` and goes to `width - 1` whereas the reversing starts at `width - 1` and goes to `0`.

Comment: Reverse of reverse = original. Don't get confused. The first piece of code is just copying the file as is. The second is reversing the rows.

Comment: The first one works but the second doesn't. Are my indices incorrect?

Comment: "Works" how? What does it do? Have you tied to compare the input file with the output?

Comment: Image file usually begins with some metadata (width, height, #colors, etc) that you should not modify. Are you sure that your file contains only pixel values?

Comment: I'm using the `.raw` file type, which should only contain pixel values. And I've opened up the output file to which I'm greeted with `Windows cannot display this image. Either the image is corrupt or is too large.`

Comment: But surely Windows cannot show images that "only cntain pixel values"?? How would it know what its width is, and its height, and, for that matter, that it is a grayscale image? You cannot view the original with Windows either, can you?

Comment: I can view the original with Windows, as I installed the Microsoft Camera Codec pack. In Windows Photo Viewer I see the resulting image if I run my program using the first bit of code, but don't see anything when running the second bit.

Comment: but viewing it in an image viewer doesn't mean there's no metadata; why would it? if there's no metadata, then you should be able to output only the second half of the data into a new file and still be able to view it (that would be a good experiment!). but i agree with the others: there's almost certainly metadata that belongs at the beginning or the end of the file. you could do some more experimenting with your code (or a hex editor) to determine where the metadata ends and the image begins and then add the logic to preserve it's position in the course of any transformation

Comment: It's easy to check. Compare the file size in bytes to the `width x height x color depth`. If they are the same - no metadata is added. If not - some extra info is in the file.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: yes -- and the numbers can tell even more than that. Equal: no extra data at all. Larger: yup, metadata. Much larger: *lots* of metadata. Magnitudes larger: It May Not Be Grayscale After All. Smaller, on the other hand:, means the raw file has some sort of compression.